# How do I implement the RandomSwitch() function using a loop?

Tags: vb.net

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If PictureBox1.Visible = True Then 'if picture box 1 is visible (initially visible) then
        PictureBox1.Visible = False 'picture box 1 is hidden and
        PictureBox2.Visible = True 'picture box 2 is visible (initially hidden)
        Label1.Text = "OFF" 'label reads that the light is OFF (initially reads ON)
    ElseIf PictureBox2.Visible = True Then 'if picture box 2 is visible then
        PictureBox2.Visible = False 'picture box 2 is hidden and
        PictureBox1.Visible = True 'picture box 1 is visible
        Label1.Text = "ON" 'label reads that the light is ON
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Application.Exit() 'closes the form

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim generator As New Random


    Do

        If PictureBox1.Visible = True Then 'if picture box 1 is visible (initially visible) then
        PictureBox1.Visible = False 'picture box 1 is hidden and
        PictureBox2.Visible = True 'picture box 2 is visible (initially hidden)
        Label1.Text = "OFF" 'label reads that the light is OFF (initially reads ON)
    ElseIf PictureBox2.Visible = True Then 'if picture box 2 is visible then
        PictureBox2.Visible = False 'picture box 2 is hidden and
        PictureBox1.Visible = True 'picture box 1 is visible
        Label1.Text = "ON" 'label reads that the light is ON
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

1.How do I make Button 2 do what Button 1 does but it has to do chose to do it n number of times at random. Limit is from 1-20 times.

Comment: What is RandomSwitch?

Comment: If you want to call a method in an event handler then the best thing to do is call that method within that event handler. You're not doing that at the moment, so that's your biggest issue. If you want to call the method within a loop, you probably ought to call it within a loop. If you want to reset a state after an action then the thing to do is to remember what that state was before performing the action. The way to remember a state is to set one or more appropriate variables.

Comment: If you want to do something random in VB.NET then you create a `Random` object and then call the appropriate method to generate a random number. How you then use that number depends on your app. If you're selecting randomly between two things, generating a random `Integer` from 0 to 1 and then using that as an index into an array containing those things is the obvious option.

Comment: Im trying to make "Button 2" do what "Button 1" does already but I wanted it where it will do it from 1-20 times randomly but I just don't know how to start it. Im new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code of how to use the Random class. The only trouble is that the loop will execute so fast that you won't see anything.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim rnd As New Random
        Dim NumberOfLoops = rnd.Next(1, 21)
        'The returned Integer will be equal to or more than 1 and less than 21
        Dim Counter As Integer = 1
        Do
            If PictureBox1.Visible = True Then
                Label1.Text = "On"
            Else
                Label1.text = "Off"
            End If
            PictureBox1.Visible = Not PictureBox1.Visible
            PictureBox2.Visible = Not PictureBox2.Visible
            Counter += 1
        Loop While NumberOfLoops <= Counter

End Sub
```